# How to stay on same step of sap.m Wizard?

Tags: sapui5, wizard, sap-fiori

I have an input validation after pressing the NextStep button in sap.m wizard.

If input validation fails, I have to stay on same step. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you provide further information? What are you validating, how the algorithm look like, whats your input like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at SAP API Documentation for sap.m.Wizard and sap.m.WizardStep.
For sap.m.Wizard, it states:

Next Step Button

The next step button is displayed below the content. It can be hidden by setting showNextButton to false and displayed, for example, only after the user has filled all mandatory fields. 
So depending on the validation routine, the button “Next Step” can be hidden to prevent the user moving to the next step.

There is also an example in SAP Explored.

Comment: Thank you , I Have validated it in the liveChange event of Input Field